# In Google AutoML vision, is it possible to generate a localization map of the important regions in the image (heatmap)?

Tags: google-cloud-automl

I’m new to machine learning. I am working with a public dataset of medical images and Google’s AutoML vision. My goal is to create a multi-class classifier using single-label classification to diagnose different diseases based on labeled photos.

I was wondering if it was possible to obtain heat maps of regions in the photos that the learning algorithm relied on to make its prediction. This would make the algorithm more clinician-friendly and more understandable. In CNNs, I think this concept is called gradient-weighted class activation mapping (grad-cam).

Please let me know if this is possible with Google AutoML. Thanks a lot